# adding to a specific cell in a listview - powershell

Tags: powershell

So i have a listview in my xaml that is supposed to be populated by a user search my question is, how do i add to a single cell in a listview? i tried the same format as c# (my primary programming language) but didn't have any luck

the listview is here:

```
<ListView x:Name="lbResults" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="156" Margin="24,195,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="511" FontSize="16">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Ip" Width="120"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="120"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Time"  Width="120"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and my current code:

```
Function Get-Data
{
    param([string]$Localusername)

    $WPFLbResults.Items.Add("BCDC01", 1)
    $results1 =  
    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName bcdc01 -FilterHashtable @{logname='security';id=4771;data=$Localusername} |
    Select-Object -Property timecreated,
    @{Name='computername';expression={$_.properties[6].value.Split(':')[3]}}


    foreach($string in $results1)
    {
         $WPFLvResults.Items.Add($string, 1)
    }
    $WPFLbResults.Items.Add("BCDC02", 1)

    $results2 =  
    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName bcdc02 -FilterHashtable @{logname='security';id=4771;data=$Localusername} |
    Select-Object -Property timecreated,
    @{Name='computername';expression={$_.properties[6].value.Split(':')[3]}}

    foreach($string in $results2)
    {
         $WPFLbResults.Items.Add($string, 1)
    }

    $WPFLbResults.Items.Add("BCDC05", 1)

    $results3 =  
    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName bcdc05 -FilterHashtable @{logname='security';id=4771;data=$Localusername} |
    Select-Object -Property timecreated,
    @{Name='computername';expression={$_.properties[6].value.Split(':')[3]}}

    foreach($string in $results3)
    {
         $WPFLbResults.Items.Add($string, 1)
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say "single cell", are you talking about adding a data row, or adding a new column?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen adding data to a single cell (or is it a field? im not sure) in a new data row to a list view